# Issue calling unmanaged code from C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, unmanaged, vb6-migration

I'm am having trouble communicating between COM components.

I have three components

1. Application A, which uses
2. the Bridge, which is written in VB6 and is COM visible
3. Application B, which is also written in VB6 and exposes a COM interface

In the past, whoever starts up first, Application A or B, will create a Bridge using VB6's `CreateObject([ProgId])` function. This seems to create only ever create 1 instance of the Bridge, as calling `CreateObject([ProdId])` again will return the same Bridge. This is great because there should only ever be one of Application A and one of Application B and they should both share the same Bridge which they make COM calls to.

Now I need to make a version of Application B in C#. When I have Application A start, create the Bridge, which then creates my C# Application B via the ProgId, messages will get sent to the Application B from A via the Bridge. That's great. The problem is when I try to get the Bridge from my C# application. Calling `Activator.CreateInstance([ProgId of Bridge])` does not have the same effect as calling `CreateObject` in VB6- instead of getting the same Bridge object as Application A has, `CreateInstance` returns a new Bridge, which isn't wired up to Application A.

In fact, the new Bridge will try to create a new Instance of A, which would be the correct behaviour if there wasn't already an Application A in existence.

The problem is made more difficult by the fact that I cannot modify the source of the Bridge or Application A in any way.  I understand the problem has something to do with how managed versus unmanaged code is handled in Windows, and that C# code is Managed whereas Application A, B, and the Bridge are all written in VB6 and are therefore not managed.

My question is, is there a way to somehow find the Bridge object that application A creates- that is, is there some special "Activator.CreateInstance()" method that I have overlooked? If not, what is the standard way of communicating between managed and unmanaged COM components. (I have tried looking into pipes, but that essentially means that the serialization of method calls must be done manually which is where I'd really prefer a COM solution).

Please ask me to elaborate on anything and I'll try my best; I'm new to COM, and VB6.

Comment: Is the original solution using MTS/COM+/Component Services?  The statement that CreateObject([ProgID]) returns the same bridge is not how VB6/COM works.  VB6, by default, will create a new instance of the object for each CreateObject call.  So something else must be at play to have it return the same instance always.  MTS/COM+ can do that.  If MTS/COM+ is being used then you need to make sure you C# component is also using COM+ (referred to as Enterprise Services in .NET).

Comment: How would I be able to tell which service it uses- Would that be stated somewhere in the VB6 source?

Comment: Try looking for any calls to "SetComplete()" or "SetAbort()" in your code.  Can look for a reference to "COM+ Services Type Library" in the project references.  Can also look for instances of "COMSVCSLib" library in your code, such as "COMSVCSLib.IObjectConstruct" or "COMSVCSLib.ObjectControl" or "COMSVCSLib.ObjectContext".  Those are all COM+ features.  There are others to look for, but those are pretty common.

Comment: It doesn't have any of those, however it does reference OLE Automation. Does that help?

Comment: I don't think its is the bridge, I think it is how you are calling the COM component.  You don't need to use Activator.CreateInstance.  You can just use "New" after you have generated the Interops for the COM object.  It acts just like a .NET object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to be the case. I have done something like: DefaultBridge bridge = new DefaultBridge(); versus DefaultBridge bridge = (DefaultBridge)Activator.CreateInstance([prodId]);